# iMessage not working

Tags: iphone, messaging

I'm not sure if here is the right place to ask, migrate if you think it does not.

Recently I have a lot of problems with Apple's iMessage service. On a regular basis it tells me that the recipient is not able to receive iMessages at the time (since it's an ipod it is also not possible to send a regular text message). That person tells me however that she has no problem at the same time to send texts to other people via iMessage but also has trouble to send them to me. So it seems like a problem at my end. Could this be an issue with my provider? But I thought I also ran into that problem when connected to a WiFi.
What are my options to check for a possible failure on my end?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a working internet connection, so make sure you can check email, use a Safari, etc, when you are seeing the problems. Also try multiple people at the same time when you see the problem, to see if it's everyone or just one person. Remember that they will also have to have iMessage, so if you are syncing contacts and have a regular SMS number there conflicting with an iMessage one, or an iCloud/Apple account, that may be getting in the way too. Apart from narrowing it down like that, there's not a huge amount you can do.

Comment: I did the internet check (just open safari and reloaded the current page which always works fine). I even have 3G and not just Edge. I also tried another person (that has a iPhone, not just an iPod) and instead of an iMessage I sent a normal message. I have no cloud  services activated apart from FindMyiPhone. Anyway, thanks for the effort

Comment: Is it possible that you could be connected to a Wifi access point that doesn't give you strong access, or you have to manually log in to get access to the internet with? For instance, some coffee shops or stores with free wifi have no security on the network, but you must login via a web page or similar to actually go online. Could there be an access point like this interfering with your 3G (i.e. trying to override it) connection? When this happens I have to manually disable Wifi so that it can fall back to the 3G.